# The entity type 'Service' requires a primary key to be defined. But I already defined it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, database

First time useing .NET core and first time using inmemoryDB. I have a CarContext class which has a DbSet. I just want to load up my inmemoryDatabase with sample data because when I tried to run it, it crashed due to getting null from the database.

Here is my CarContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MechanicNote.Models
{
    public class CarContext : DbContext
    {
        public CarContext(DbContextOptions<CarContext> dbContextOptions)
            : base(dbContextOptions)
        {
        }
        public CarContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<CarModel> CarModels {get;set;}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CarContext>()
                .HasNoKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my StartUp.cs where you can see the Seed() method which tries to seed the database, and I get the no primary key error at the line: 72

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MechanicNote.Interfaces;
using MechanicNote.Models;
using MechanicNote.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MechanicNote
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<CarContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("CarList"));
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton<ICarModelService, CarModelService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            Seed(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CarContext>());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

       

        public static void Seed(CarContext context)
        {
                context.AddRange
                    (
                        new CarModel {Id = 1, Make = "Ford", Model = "Focus", Year = 2000, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN,ServicesDone = new List<Service>() ,ServicesQueue = new List<Service>()},
                        new CarModel {Id = 1, Make = "Alfa", Model = "Giulia", Year = 2019, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN,ServicesDone = new List<Service>() ,ServicesQueue = new List<Service>()},
                        new CarModel {Id = 1, Make = "BWM", Model = "M3", Year = 2018, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN,ServicesDone = new List<Service>() ,ServicesQueue = new List<Service>()},
                        new CarModel {Id = 1, Make = "AUDI", Model = "RS4", Year = 219, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN,ServicesDone = new List<Service>() ,ServicesQueue = new List<Service>()}
                    );
            

        context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Service.cs a service here means just a service for the car(for example oil change) and every car has a List ServicesDone and a List ServicesQueue.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MechanicNote.Models
{
    
    public class Service
    {
        private string Name{get;set;}
        private int Time{get;set;}
        private int Price{get;set;}

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Service service &&
                   Name == service.Name;
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your model does not have a property that will be determined to be the key by convention and you do not annotate any properties as the key - so, it does not have a key. Your seed operation loads `CarModel`, not `Service`.

Comment: Ahh I see. I fixed it, and now it's running, but the problem is I get this error message:

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

So the seeding was faulty. Am I right?

Comment: are you using [keyless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=fluent-api) entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to define your context class `CarContext` as an entity.

Your context class is what gives you access to the defined entities in your application `Service` and `CarModel`.

your context should posibly look something like:

```
public class CarContext : DbContext
{
   public CarContext(DbContextOptions<CarContext> dbContextOptions)
   : base(dbContextOptions)
   { }

   public CarContext()
   { }

   public DbSet<CarModel> CarModels {get;set;}
   public DbSet<Service> Services {get;set;}

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.Entity<CarModel>();
      modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().HasNoKey();
   }
}
```

you should not map the `CarContext` as a DbSet.

Your seed should work fine after that, but also make sure your Ids are different for each record, at the moment they are all 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to establish a one to many relationship between cars and services I.e. one car can have many services. You are not seeding your data correctly and the service model is not properly written. Change the model to include a `CarModel` foreignkey like this:

```
public class Service
{
    public int ServiceId {get;set;}
    public int CarModelId {get;set;}
    private string Name{get;set;}
    private int Time{get;set;}
    private int Price{get;set;}
    public CarModel CarModel {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Service service &&
               Name == service.Name;
    }
}
```

Then seed the data like this: You do not need to define an `ICollection<Service>` in the instantiation of your `CarModel` class. You reference it with the car foreign Id (`CarModelId`) when you seed the `Service` model (like I have done at the end of this answer), it will be aware of which CarModel the service belongs.

```
context.AddRange
(
    new CarModel {Id = 1, Make = "Ford", Model = "Focus", Year = 2000, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN},
    new CarModel {Id = 2, Make = "Alfa", Model = "Giulia", Year = 2019, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN ()},
    new CarModel {Id = 3, Make = "BWM", Model = "M3", Year = 2018, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN()},
    new CarModel {Id = 4, Make = "AUDI", Model = "RS4", Year = 219, Type = Enums.TypeEnum.SEDAN()}
)
```

Seed your service class like this: Notice how there are two services for each `CarModel` category

```
context.AddRange
(
    new Service {ServiceId = 1, CarModelId = 1, Name = "Oil Filter Replacement", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 4000},
    new Service {ServiceId = 2, CarModelId = 1, Name = "Wheels Alignment", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 2000},
    new Service {ServiceId = 3, CarModelId = 2, Name = "Oil Filter Replacement", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 4000},
    new Service {ServiceId = 4, CarModelId = 2, Name = "Wheels Alignment", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 4000},
    new Service {ServiceId = 5, CarModelId = 3, Name = "Brake Pad Replacement", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 4000},
    new Service {ServiceId = 6, CarModelId = 3, Name = "Shock Absorber repair", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 8500},
    new Service {ServiceId = 7, CarModelId = 4, Name = "Oil Filter Replacement", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 4000},
    new Service {ServiceId = 8, CarModelId = 4, Name = "Wheels Alignment", Time = DateTime.Now, Price = 4000},
)
```

Note: You might need to make some modifications for this answer to suit your needs.